# split json on logstash udp input

Tags: json, udp, logstash

one of our application sending logs to remote server via udp on JSON format.
some of the logs are chained JSON strings such as the one below:

> {"s":1,"x":"foo"}{"s":1,"p":"bar"}

i'm using the the following filter to split the messages.
when the input is file, the logs split and i get multiple events.
however, when i use udp input, its not split the string and create only single event from the first JSON.

> ```
> filter {
>     mutate {
>        gsub => [ "message","}{","}#{"]
>     }
>     split {
>        terminator => [ "#" ]
>     }
>     if [message] =~ /^{.*}$/  {
>        json {
>            source => message
>        }
>     }
> }
> ```

does anyone know what's wrong here?

Comment: What does your "message" field look like after being processed by logstash?

Comment: when sending the data via udp it appears  that "\u0000" was added between the brackets so gsub functions didnt do what is should do. this update configuration solved this issue -   filter {
    mutate {
       gsub => [ "message","}\u0000{","}#{"]
    }
    split {
       terminator => [ "#" ]
    }
    if [message] =~ /^{.*}$/  {
       json {
           source => message
       }
    }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as it looks, i replied on the wrong location as well. 
this what solve it:

when sending the data via udp it appears that "\u0000" was added between the brackets so gsub functions didnt replace the char as i want it to.
this update configuration solved this issue -

```
filter {
              mutate {
                 gsub => [ "message","}\u0000{","}#{"] 
              } 
              split { 
                 terminator => [ "#" ] 
              } 
              if [message] =~ /^{.*}$/ { 
                 json { source => message }
              }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since my comment was on the right path, I'll move it here as an answer:

Check what logstash is sending to elasticsearch via the stdout{} output function.  If you have characters that don't match your pattern, the logic won't fire.